# How does Ansible determine which vault to use when there are multiple vaults?

Tags: ansible

I have scoured through the web and the ansible documentation, but I have not been able to find an answer for this question.

Say the structure is as follows:

`./playbooks/foo.yml`
`./hosts/HOST_NAME`  (Contains IP for a specific host)
`./hosts/host_vars/HOST_NAME/vault1`
`./hosts/host_vars/HOST_NAME/vault2`

When I run the command:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts/HOST_NAME playbooks/foo.yml`

1. Will ansible use vault1 or vault2 per default?
2. If it looks in both, what happens if both vaults have defined the same variable? That is:

   - vault1 -> username: user1
   - vault2 -> username: user2
3. If it looks in both, will the command fail if one of the vaults fail the decryption?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q1: ***"Will Ansible use vault1 or vault2 per default?"***

A: Both. In the sort order.

---

Q2: ***"What happens if both vaults have defined the same variable?"***

A: The last one wins.

---

Q3: ***"Will the command fail if one of the vaults fails the decryption?"***

A: Yes.

---

Example: Given the tree

```
shell> tree ../test-915
../test-915
├── ansible.cfg
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   └── test_11
│       ├── vault1
│       └── vault2
└── pb.yml
```

the unencrypted vaults

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/test_11/vault1 
username: user1
key1: val1
shell> cat host_vars/test_11/vault2
username: user2
key2: val2
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml 
- hosts: test_11
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: |
          username: {{ username }}
          key1: {{ key1 }}
          key2: {{ key2 }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [test_11] **********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    username: user2
    key1: val1
    key2: val2
```